# Getting the error TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

For the past two days, I am stuck with this error TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor.
Here is my html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css"></script>


<body class="dt-example">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>BDM</th>
                <th>AE APO NO</th>
                <th>CUST NO</th>
                <th>CUST NAME</th>
                <th>BRAND</th>
                <th>PNC NO</th>
                <th>MODEL</th>
                <th>REQ QTY</th>

                <th>PG DESC</th>
                <th>PG CODE</th>
                <th>COUNTRY</th>
                <th>MONTH DELIV.</th>
                <th>SU</th>
                <th>CSS TEAM</th>
                <th>SO ORDER NO</th>
                <th>DIRECT/CONS</th>
                <th>PO NOs.</th>
                <th>DIRECT/CONS</th>
                <th>ORDER DATE</th>
                <th>REQ DELIVERY DATE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>


<script>




    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "aProcessing": true,
            "aServerSide": true,
            "ajax": "server-response.php",
        } );


});


var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "server-response.php",
        table: "#example",

        formOptions: {
            bubble: {
                title: 'Edit',
                buttons: false
            }
        }
    } );

    /*$('button.new').on( 'click', function () {
        editor
        .title( 'Create new row' )
        .buttons( { "label": "Add", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } } )
        .create();
    } );

    $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function (e) {
        if ( $(this).index() < 6 ) {
            editor.bubble( this );
        }
    } );

    $('#example').on( 'click', 'a.remove', function (e) {
        editor
        .title( 'Delete row' )
        .message( 'Are you sure you wish to delete this row?' )
        .buttons( { "label": "Delete", "fn": function () { editor.submit() } } )
        .remove( $(this).closest('tr') );
    } ); */
});

</script>

</html>
```

Here is my php code :

```
 <?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array( 'bdm', 'ae_apo_no', 'customer_no', 'cust_name',
        'brand','pnc_no','model','req_qty','pg_desc','pg_code','country',
        'month_delivery','su','css_id','so_order_no','d_c','po_no','order_date','req_delivery_date');

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "orders";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "root";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "tracker";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }


    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
    }


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }


    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    /*
     * Output
     */
    /*
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    */

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

/*     print_r($output);
*/    
echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

I have tried solving it using the following links, but with no effect.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21764/fn-datatable-editor-is-not-a-constructor-requirejs-with-datatables

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see `datatables.editor.js` in your code! make sure you have included it too.